# Constrained Optimization with Interpolating Functions

Tags: mathematical-optimization, interpolation, constraint

My goal is to use a gradient descent type method to maximize interpolating function1 with respect to the constraint that interpolating function2 <= 0.5. I am working with 4D data (please see below).

I created the two interpolating functions as follows:

```
f1 = Interpolation[data1, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
f2 = Interpolation[data2, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
```

And then I used the code outlined in this resource https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Books/8506/ConstrainedOptimization.pdf:

```
NMinimize[{-f2, f1 <=  0.5}, {x, y, z}]
Minimize[{-f2, f1 <=  0.5}, {x, y, z}]
FindMinimum[{-f2, f1 <=  0.5}, {x, y, z}]
```

NMinimize gives the error message: "NMinimize::bcons: The following constraints are not valid: {InterpolatingFunction[{{4.,8.},{0.5,7.},{0.7,2.}},{5,4225,0,{954,0,6},{2,2,2},0,0,0,0,Automatic,{},{},False},{<<23>>[{<<1>>},{<<1>>},{<<1>>}]},{0.750342,0.64151,0.622998,0.730189,0.236956,0.0920386,0.0884832,<<37>>,0.000752695,0.000144944,0.0000162,3.72*10^-6,2.67*10^-6,0.316358,<<904>>},{Automatic}]<=<<4>>}. Constraints should be equalities, inequalities, or domain specifications involving the variables."

Minimize gives no resulting value and just outputs the same thing that I input.

Find Minimum gives the error "FindInstance::exvar: The system contains a nonconstant expression InterpolatingFunction[{{4.,8.},{0.5,7.},{0.7,2.}},{5,4225,0,{954,0,6},{2,2,2},0,0,0,0,Automatic,{},{},False},{<<1>>},{0.750342,0.64151,0.622998,0.730189,0.236956,0.0920386,0.0884832,0.948879,<<35>>,0.00922568,0.000752695,0.000144944,0.0000162,3.72*10^-6,2.67*10^-6,0.316358,<<904>>},{Automatic}] independent of variables {[FormalX],[FormalY],[FormalZ]}."

Any help figuring out how to do this type of optimization will be very greatly appreciated. I have never done this in Mathematica and I am very confused.

Here is some of the data that I used in case anyone wants to test out what I'm talking about:

```
data1 = {{{4.0, 2.5, 0.7}, 0.750341814}, {{4.0, 2.75, 0.7}, 
   0.641510140}, {{4.0, 3.0, 0.7}, 0.622998451}, {{4.5, 2.3, 0.7}, 
   0.730188891}, {{4.5, 2.6, 0.7}, 0.236956251}, {{4.5, 3.2, 0.7}, 
   0.092038571}, {{4.5, 3.5, 0.7}, 0.088483203}, {{5.0, 2.25, 0.7}, 
   0.948879277}, {{5.0, 2.6, 0.7}, 0.190624075}, {{5.0, 2.95, 0.7}, 
   0.135275036}, {{5.0, 3.3, 0.7}, 0.032763743}, {{5.0, 3.65, 0.7}, 
   0.029430211}, {{5.0, 4.0, 0.7}, 0.027537075}, {{5.5, 2.5, 0.7}, 
   0.281232137}, {{5.5, 2.9, 0.7}, 0.054980707}, {{5.5, 3.3, 0.7}, 
   0.023085488}, {{5.5, 3.7, 0.7}, 0.031317836}, {{5.5, 4.1, 0.7}, 
   0.010820878}, {{5.5, 4.5, 0.7}, 0.010161860}, {{6.0, 2.3, 0.7}, 
   0.397089577}, {{6.0, 2.75, 0.7}, 0.074292346}, {{6.0, 3.2, 0.7}, 
   0.015918433}, {{6.0, 3.65, 0.7}, 0.004494633}, {{6.0, 4.1, 0.7}, 
   0.002195262}, {{6.0, 4.55, 0.7}, 0.001750180}, {{6.0, 5.0, 0.7}, 
   0.001701018}, {{6.5, 2.5, 0.7}, 0.322173220}, {{6.5, 3.0, 0.7}, 
   0.037894300}, {{6.5, 3.5, 0.7}, 0.005178418}, {{6.5, 4.0, 0.7}, 
   0.001170227}, {{6.5, 4.5, 0.7}, 0.001044620}, {{6.5, 5.0, 0.7}, 
   0.000228311}, {{6.5, 5.5, 0.7}, 0.000204873}, {{7.0, 2.15, 0.7}, 
   0.799562745}, {{7.0, 2.7, 0.7}, 0.169379167}, {{7.0, 3.25, 0.7}, 
   0.019800399}, {{7.0, 3.8, 0.7}, 0.001902681}, {{7.0, 4.35, 0.7}, 
   0.000501842}, {{7.0, 4.9, 0.7}, 0.000126206}, {{7.0, 5.45, 0.7}, 
   0.000026700}, {{7.0, 6.0, 0.7}, 0.000020600}, {{7.5, 2.3, 0.7}, 
   1.215594070}, {{7.5, 2.9, 0.7}, 0.050740772}, {{7.5, 3.5, 0.7}, 
   0.009225684}, {{7.5, 4.1, 0.7}, 0.000752695}, {{7.5, 4.7, 0.7}, 
   0.000144944}, {{7.5, 5.3, 0.7}, 0.000016200}, {{7.5, 5.9, 0.7}, 
   0.000003720}, {{7.5, 6.5, 0.7}, 0.000002670}, {{8.0, 2.45, 0.7}, 
   0.316357500}, {{8.0, 3.1, 0.7}, 0.049589355}, {{8.0, 3.75, 0.7}, 
   0.001624453}, {{8.0, 4.4, 0.7}, 0.000321852}, {{8.0, 5.05, 0.7}, 
   0.000043800}, {{8.0, 5.7, 0.7}, 0.000003320}, {{8.0, 6.35, 0.7}, 
   0.000001040}, {{8.0, 7.0, 0.7}, 0.000000425}, {{4.0, 2.0, 0.83}, 
   1.123030977}, {{4.0, 2.25, 0.83}, 0.643862594}, {{4.0, 2.5, 0.83}, 
   0.494527641}, {{4.0, 2.75, 0.83}, 0.460772203}, {{4.0, 3.0, 0.83}, 
   0.449952666}, {{4.5, 2.0, 0.83}, 1.177597462}, {{4.5, 2.3, 0.83}, 
   0.246286304}, {{4.5, 2.6, 0.83}, 0.126303219}, {{4.5, 2.9, 0.83}, 
   0.805843164}, {{4.5, 3.2, 0.83}, 0.064124542}, {{4.5, 3.5, 0.83}, 
   0.063221002}, {{5.0, 1.9, 0.83}, 0.959095797}, {{5.0, 2.25, 0.83}, 
   0.395763200}, {{5.0, 2.6, 0.83}, 0.068053440}, {{5.0, 2.95, 0.83}, 
   0.058924421}, {{5.0, 3.3, 0.83}, 0.018638068}, {{5.0, 3.65, 0.83}, 
   0.016715326}, {{5.0, 4.0, 0.83}, 0.016485697}, {{5.5, 2.1, 0.83}, 
   0.801945073}, {{5.5, 2.5, 0.83}, 0.121609842}, {{5.5, 2.9, 0.83}, 
   0.022526237}, {{5.5, 3.3, 0.83}, 0.010862152}, {{5.5, 3.7, 0.83}, 
   0.010286207}, {{5.5, 4.1, 0.83}, 0.007491423}, {{5.5, 4.5, 0.83}, 
   0.007211895}, {{6.0, 2.3, 0.83}, 0.160576165}, {{6.0, 2.75, 0.83}, 
   0.029644050}, {{6.0, 3.2, 0.83}, 0.007040139}, {{6.0, 3.65, 0.83}, 
   0.003064983}, {{6.0, 4.1, 0.83}, 0.002347885}, {{6.0, 4.55, 0.83}, 
   0.002231154}, {{6.0, 5.0, 0.83}, 0.002229741}, {{6.5, 2.0, 0.83}, 
   0.743003719}, {{6.5, 2.5, 0.83}, 0.091745464}, {{6.5, 3.0, 0.83}, 
   0.011634382}, {{6.5, 3.5, 0.83}, 0.001858806}, {{6.5, 4.0, 0.83}, 
   0.000625568}, {{6.5, 4.5, 0.83}, 0.000476692}, {{6.5, 5.0, 0.83}, 
   0.000270385}, {{6.5, 5.5, 0.83}, 0.000263443}, {{7.0, 2.15, 0.83}, 
   0.289692249}, {{7.0, 2.7, 0.83}, 0.070986865}, {{7.0, 3.25, 0.83}, 
   0.005445419}, {{7.0, 3.8, 0.83}, 0.000569259}, {{7.0, 4.35, 0.83}, 
   0.000184639}, {{7.0, 4.9, 0.83}, 0.000050600}, {{7.0, 5.45, 0.83}, 
   0.000019100}, {{7.0, 6.0, 0.83}, 0.000017700}, {{7.5, 2.3, 0.83}, 
   0.427847385}, {{7.5, 2.9, 0.83}, 0.016100380}, {{7.5, 3.5, 0.83}, 
   0.003665870}, {{7.5, 4.1, 0.83}, 0.000201233}, {{7.5, 4.7, 0.83}, 
   0.000060600}, {{7.5, 5.3, 0.83}, 0.000005190}, {{7.5, 5.9, 0.83}, 
   0.000002460}, {{7.5, 6.5, 0.83}, 0.000002090}, {{8.0, 2.45, 0.83}, 
   0.096275542}, {{8.0, 3.1, 0.83}, 0.017935820}, {{8.0, 3.75, 0.83}, 
   0.000604182}, {{8.0, 4.4, 0.83}, 0.000079200}, {{8.0, 5.05, 0.83}, 
   0.000017500}, {{8.0, 5.7, 0.83}, 0.000000999}, {{8.0, 6.35, 0.83}, 
   0.000000476}, {{8.0, 7.0, 0.83}, 0.000000303}, {{4.0, 2.25, 0.96}, 
   1.177242345}, {{4.0, 2.5, 0.96}, 0.903436502}, {{4.0, 2.75, 0.96}, 
   0.332421564}, {{4.0, 3.0, 0.96}, 0.328294859}, {{4.5, 2.0, 0.96}, 
   0.610951015}, {{4.5, 2.3, 0.96}, 0.673977792}, {{4.5, 2.6, 0.96}, 
   0.108851985}, {{4.5, 2.9, 0.96}, 0.125798036}, {{4.5, 3.2, 0.96}, 
   0.164368921}, {{4.5, 3.5, 0.96}, 0.083522130}, {{5.0, 2.25, 0.96}, 
   0.173705123}, {{5.0, 2.6, 0.96}, 0.414522040}, {{5.0, 2.95, 0.96}, 
   0.197962721}, {{5.0, 3.3, 0.96}, 0.025581569}, {{5.0, 3.65, 0.96}, 
   0.026675785}, {{5.0, 4.0, 0.96}, 0.025212890}, {{5.5, 2.1, 0.96}, 
   0.441425969}, {{5.5, 2.5, 0.96}, 0.044996441}, {{5.5, 2.9, 0.96}, 
   0.306236219}, {{5.5, 3.3, 0.96}, 0.010891276}, {{5.5, 3.7, 0.96}, 
   0.006561283}, {{5.5, 4.1, 0.96}, 0.000851567}, {{5.5, 4.5, 0.96}, 
   0.000718190}, {{6.0, 1.85, 0.96}, 0.807149508}, {{6.0, 2.3, 0.96}, 
   0.065261072}, {{6.0, 2.75, 0.96}, 0.062784999}, {{6.0, 3.2, 0.96}, 
   0.073790906}, {{6.0, 3.65, 0.96}, 0.013393139}, {{6.0, 4.1, 0.96}, 
   0.002261782}, {{6.0, 4.55, 0.96}, 0.001243003}, {{6.0, 5.0, 0.96}, 
   0.001121045}, {{6.5, 2.0, 0.96}, 1.145752994}, {{6.5, 2.5, 0.96}, 
   0.190715368}, {{6.5, 3.0, 0.96}, 0.039221201}, {{6.5, 3.5, 0.96}, 
   0.023321520}, {{6.5, 4.0, 0.96}, 0.000322579}, {{6.5, 4.5, 0.96}, 
   0.000220124}, {{6.5, 5.0, 0.96}, 0.000187539}, {{6.5, 5.5, 0.96}, 
   0.000196152}, {{7.0, 2.15, 0.96}, 0.554272538}, {{7.0, 2.7, 0.96}, 
   0.028907939}, {{7.0, 3.25, 0.96}, 0.009721355}, {{7.0, 3.8, 0.96}, 
   0.002695021}, {{7.0, 4.35, 0.96}, 0.000084600}, {{7.0, 4.9, 0.96}, 
   0.000142253}, {{7.0, 5.45, 0.96}, 0.000037600}, {{7.0, 6.0, 0.96}, 
   0.000034100}};



   data2 = {{{4.0, 2.5, 0.7}, 1825638.3969999999}, {{4.0, 2.75, 0.7}, 
   1724222.467}, {{4.0, 3.0, 0.7}, 1642032.871}, {{4.5, 2.3, 0.7}, 
   1854987.9919999999}, {{4.5, 2.6, 0.7}, 
   1705997.1269999999}, {{4.5, 3.2, 0.7}, 
   1492211.864}, {{4.5, 3.5, 0.7}, 1416414.175}, {{5.0, 2.25, 0.7}, 
   1838521.2130000002}, {{5.0, 2.6, 0.7}, 
   1657210.419}, {{5.0, 2.95, 0.7}, 1515504.514}, {{5.0, 3.3, 0.7}, 
   1403475.8590000002}, {{5.0, 3.65, 0.7}, 
   1313632.943}, {{5.0, 4.0, 0.7}, 1243469.29}, {{5.5, 2.5, 0.7}, 
   1673804.5769999998}, {{5.5, 2.9, 0.7}, 
   1499202.05}, {{5.5, 3.3, 0.7}, 1363569.187}, {{5.5, 3.7, 0.7}, 
   1256514.6809999999}, {{5.5, 4.1, 0.7}, 
   1171796.743}, {{5.5, 4.5, 0.7}, 1105440.165}, {{6.0, 2.3, 0.7}, 
   1761443.8190000001}, {{6.0, 2.75, 0.7}, 
   1537810.2040000001}, {{6.0, 3.2, 0.7}, 
   1370202.236}, {{6.0, 3.65, 0.7}, 1240452.455}, {{6.0, 4.1, 0.7}, 
   1137210.962}, {{6.0, 4.55, 0.7}, 1056733.831}, {{6.0, 5.0, 0.7}, 
   994385.1308}, {{6.5, 2.5, 0.7}, 1641853.405}, {{6.5, 3.0, 0.7}, 
   1425165.07}, {{6.5, 3.5, 0.7}, 1262873.913}, {{6.5, 4.0, 0.7}, 
   1137578.723}, {{6.5, 4.5, 0.7}, 1037990.926}, {{6.5, 5.0, 0.7}, 
   961077.5862}, {{6.5, 5.5, 0.7}, 902696.5156}, {{7.0, 2.15, 0.7}, 
   1836694.5659999999}, {{7.0, 2.7, 0.7}, 
   1537852.989}, {{7.0, 3.25, 0.7}, 
   1328450.5559999999}, {{7.0, 3.8, 0.7}, 
   1171256.773}, {{7.0, 4.35, 0.7}, 1050080.866}, {{7.0, 4.9, 0.7}, 
   954035.877}, {{7.0, 5.45, 0.7}, 880665.0223}, {{7.0, 6.0, 0.7}, 
   825700.3843}, {{7.5, 2.3, 0.7}, 1739780.707}, {{7.5, 2.9, 0.7}, 
   1447164.261}, {{7.5, 3.5, 0.7}, 1241853.154}, {{7.5, 4.1, 0.7}, 
   1089986.5559999999}, {{7.5, 4.7, 0.7}, 
   973268.6319}, {{7.5, 5.3, 0.7}, 882716.8063}, {{7.5, 5.9, 0.7}, 
   812719.8843}, {{7.5, 6.5, 0.7}, 759854.6725}, {{8.0, 2.45, 0.7}, 
   1647668.73}, {{8.0, 3.1, 0.7}, 1366059.112}, {{8.0, 3.75, 0.7}, 
   1168252.432}, {{8.0, 4.4, 0.7}, 1020992.728}, {{8.0, 5.05, 0.7}, 
   908604.2184}, {{8.0, 5.7, 0.7}, 820844.7401}, {{8.0, 6.35, 0.7}, 
   753595.9017}, {{8.0, 7.0, 0.7}, 703633.5985}, {{4.0, 2.0, 0.83}, 
   2018289.761}, {{4.0, 2.25, 0.83}, 1890663.007}, {{4.0, 2.5, 0.83}, 
   1788071.095}, {{4.0, 2.75, 0.83}, 1701044.687}, {{4.0, 3.0, 0.83}, 
   1632910.4419999998}, {{4.5, 2.0, 0.83}, 
   1934243.685}, {{4.5, 2.3, 0.83}, 1779632.375}, {{4.5, 2.6, 0.83}, 
   1657469.8269999998}, {{4.5, 2.9, 0.83}, 
   1557370.45}, {{4.5, 3.2, 0.83}, 1476857.989}, {{4.5, 3.5, 0.83}, 
   1410963.305}, {{5.0, 1.9, 0.83}, 1940867.365}, {{5.0, 2.25, 0.83}, 
   1746026.48}, {{5.0, 2.6, 0.83}, 1596546.918}, {{5.0, 2.95, 0.83}, 
   1477049.404}, {{5.0, 3.3, 0.83}, 1381061.372}, {{5.0, 3.65, 0.83}, 
   1301990.0729999999}, {{5.0, 4.0, 0.83}, 
   1241398.777}, {{5.5, 2.1, 0.83}, 1785463.573}, {{5.5, 2.5, 0.83}, 
   1594840.5790000001}, {{5.5, 2.9, 0.83}, 
   1446892.08}, {{5.5, 3.3, 0.83}, 
   1331446.3059999999}, {{5.5, 3.7, 0.83}, 
   1238565.025}, {{5.5, 4.1, 0.83}, 
   1163619.8090000001}, {{5.5, 4.5, 0.83}, 
   1105297.283}, {{6.0, 2.3, 0.83}, 
   1655369.4740000002}, {{6.0, 2.75, 0.83}, 
   1469443.386}, {{6.0, 3.2, 0.83}, 1325426.857}, {{6.0, 3.65, 0.83}, 
   1212210.146}, {{6.0, 4.1, 0.83}, 1122233.172}, {{6.0, 4.55, 0.83}, 
   1050716.784}, {{6.0, 5.0, 0.83}, 995461.9561}, {{6.5, 2.0, 0.83}, 
   1798291.485}, {{6.5, 2.5, 0.83}, 1546739.957}, {{6.5, 3.0, 0.83}, 
   1363093.63}, {{6.5, 3.5, 0.83}, 1222583.733}, {{6.5, 4.0, 0.83}, 
   1111645.925}, {{6.5, 4.5, 0.83}, 1024967.692}, {{6.5, 5.0, 0.83}, 
   956236.3007}, {{6.5, 5.5, 0.83}, 903703.0732}, {{7.0, 2.15, 0.83}, 
   1700586.6619999998}, {{7.0, 2.7, 0.83}, 
   1453964.937}, {{7.0, 3.25, 0.83}, 
   1273237.4270000001}, {{7.0, 3.8, 0.83}, 
   1135337.705}, {{7.0, 4.35, 0.83}, 1027855.275}, {{7.0, 4.9, 0.83}, 
   943468.5092}, {{7.0, 5.45, 0.83}, 877501.7975}, {{7.0, 6.0, 0.83}, 
   827340.708}, {{7.5, 2.3, 0.83}, 1614584.554}, {{7.5, 2.9, 0.83}, 
   1371301.265}, {{7.5, 3.5, 0.83}, 1194308.89}, {{7.5, 4.1, 0.83}, 
   1059602.106}, {{7.5, 4.7, 0.83}, 955129.4112}, {{7.5, 5.3, 0.83}, 
   873440.8529}, {{7.5, 5.9, 0.83}, 
   810232.4509999999}, {{7.5, 6.5, 0.83}, 
   762267.3347}, {{8.0, 2.45, 0.83}, 1537762.459}, {{8.0, 3.1, 0.83}, 
   1297367.76}, {{8.0, 3.75, 0.83}, 1123677.977}, {{8.0, 4.4, 0.83}, 
   992427.6695}, {{8.0, 5.05, 0.83}, 890887.4116}, {{8.0, 5.7, 0.83}, 
   811914.6927}, {{8.0, 6.35, 0.83}, 751053.9011}, {{8.0, 7.0, 0.83}, 
   705433.4887}, {{4.0, 2.25, 0.96}, 
   1828024.7130000002}, {{4.0, 2.5, 0.96}, 
   1744444.3830000001}, {{4.0, 2.75, 0.96}, 
   1674720.746}, {{4.0, 3.0, 0.96}, 1616854.769}, {{4.5, 2.0, 0.96}, 
   1829325.034}, {{4.5, 2.3, 0.96}, 1710008.313}, {{4.5, 2.6, 0.96}, 
   1610703.7030000002}, {{4.5, 2.9, 0.96}, 
   1527864.519}, {{4.5, 3.2, 0.96}, 
   1459332.9419999998}, {{4.5, 3.5, 0.96}, 
   1403317.9719999998}, {{5.0, 2.25, 0.96}, 
   1661860.34}, {{5.0, 2.6, 0.96}, 1539826.333}, {{5.0, 2.95, 0.96}, 
   1440650.7680000002}, {{5.0, 3.3, 0.96}, 
   1358658.493}, {{5.0, 3.65, 0.96}, 1291758.576}, {{5.0, 4.0, 0.96}, 
   1237451.801}, {{5.5, 2.1, 0.96}, 1675487.35}, {{5.5, 2.5, 0.96}, 
   1523401.9230000002}, {{5.5, 2.9, 0.96}, 
   1400769.7219999998}, {{5.5, 3.3, 0.96}, 
   1301829.295}, {{5.5, 3.7, 0.96}, 1220936.543}, {{5.5, 4.1, 0.96}, 
   1155585.378}, {{5.5, 4.5, 0.96}, 
   1103793.0729999999}, {{6.0, 1.85, 0.96}, 
   1757955.146}, {{6.0, 2.3, 0.96}, 1561884.72}, {{6.0, 2.75, 0.96}, 
   1407948.372}, {{6.0, 3.2, 0.96}, 1285886.175}, {{6.0, 3.65, 0.96}, 
   1187551.9270000001}, {{6.0, 4.1, 0.96}, 
   1108199.767}, {{6.0, 4.55, 0.96}, 
   1044915.8470000001}, {{6.0, 5.0, 0.96}, 
   995178.0803}, {{6.5, 2.0, 0.96}, 
   1663896.2219999998}, {{6.5, 2.5, 0.96}, 
   1464140.99}, {{6.5, 3.0, 0.96}, 1310108.155}, {{6.5, 3.5, 0.96}, 
   1188448.767}, {{6.5, 4.0, 0.96}, 1091521.031}, {{6.5, 4.5, 0.96}, 
   1013705.87}, {{6.5, 5.0, 0.96}, 952292.5175}, {{6.5, 5.5, 0.96}, 
   904596.5571}, {{7.0, 2.15, 0.96}, 1581377.844}, {{7.0, 2.7, 0.96}, 
   1379491.4209999999}, {{7.0, 3.25, 0.96}, 
   1225531.168}, {{7.0, 3.8, 0.96}, 1105133.229}, {{7.0, 4.35, 0.96}, 
   1009706.7059999999}, {{7.0, 4.9, 0.96}, 
   933709.8657}, {{7.0, 5.45, 0.96}, 873895.2218}, {{7.0, 6.0, 0.96}, 
   828561.4393}};
```

Comment: Probably you want to use `NMinimize[{-f2[x,y,z], f1[x,y,z] <=  0.5}, {x, y, z}]`.

Comment: Also, many optimization algorithms won't work well because you use `InterpolationOrder -> 1`. That means that the functions `f1` and `f2` are not differentiable. `InterpolationOrder -> 3` should cure this.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thank you! I actually just realized this a moment ago. Unfortunately when I add the [x,y,z] I am still getting errors. It did give a value when I dropped the constraint. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Depends on the error you get (I have not tried the code myself).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Every time I tried to increase the interpolation order it gave me an unstructured grid warning. I think this may be fixed by sorting the data (from similar posts I have encountered) but I don't know how to do this for my data set. Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this? Thank you again!

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher The new error messages when I add the [x,y,z] for NMinimize is very similar to the old one "NMinimize::bcons: The following constraints are not valid: {f1[x,y,z]<=0.5}. Constraints should be equalities, inequalities, or domain specifications involving the variables." The new error message for FindMinimum is "FindMinimum::nrlnum: The function value {0.5 -f1[1.,1.,1.]} is not a list of real numbers with dimensions {1} at {x,y,z} = {1.,1.,1.}." and Minimum still just outputs the input line. Thanks!

Comment: Who or what is `floss`? Your functions are called `f1` and `f2`, no?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher my apologies I edited it to fix it. The code I am running has some weird names so I tried to simplify it for the post. floss is just f1

Comment: You datasets seem to cover different regions in the `{x,y,z}` space. Is this supposed to be like this or is this just a copying error?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher The data1 set gives loss associated with each {x,y,z} and the data2 set gives Electric field intensity for each {x,y,z}. The full data sets have the exact same {x,y,z} values but I could not fit the full data sets in the question so I may have cut them off incorrectly. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try somthing like this. Using a `MeshRegion` as domain guarantess that the optimization algorithm won't leave the domain of definition of `f1` and `f2`. (Using `f1` and `f2` for extrapolation might do crazy things.) Not having the data, I cannot check whether this works...

```
R1 = ConvexHullMesh[data1[[All, 1]]];
R2 = ConvexHullMesh[data2[[All, 1]]];
R = RegionIntersection[R1, R2];
f1 = Interpolation[data1, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
f2 = Interpolation[data2, InterpolationOrder -> 1];

sol = NMinimize[
        {-f2[x, y, z], f1[x, y, z] <= 0.5}, 
        {x, y, z} \[Element] R
      ]

X = {x, y, z} /. sol[[2]];
f1 @@ X <= 0.5
RegionMember[R, X]
```

> True

> True

For some reason, the kernel crashes on this. But as piecwise-linear functions on some tetrahedral mesh are minimized:
Those attain there extrema also on the set of vertices -- and the latter are precisely the points in the datasets. So this should also find the minimum:

```
pos = Position[data1[[All, 2]], _?(# <= 0.5 &)];
minind = Ordering[Extract[-data2[[All, 2]], pos], -1, 1][[1]];
minimum = data2[[pos[[minind, 1]], 1]]
minvalue = data2[[pos[[minind, 1]], 2]]
```

> `{8., 7., 2.}`

> `722571.`

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have tried it and I got several errors before the kernel quits. I have updated the data so the {x,y,z} regions match

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher `data1`and `data2` are provided at the and of the question. Itrie your code: It evaluates together with some messages `{-2.40514*10^6, {x -> 1.08319, y -> 1.66811, z -> 1.25984}} `

Comment: Most of the errors I got were of the type InterpolatingFunction::femdmval: Input value {0.652468,0.63307,0.682813} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function.

Comment: I also got an error: NMinimize::incst: NMinimize was unable to generate any initial points satisfying the inequality constraints {-0.5+InterpolatingFunction[{{4.,8.},{0.5,7.},{0.7,2.}},{5,4225,0,{954,0,6},{2,2,2},0,0,0,0,Automatic,{},{},False},{<<23>>[<<1>>]},{0.750342,0.64151,0.622998,0.730189,0.236956,0.0920386,0.0884832,<<37>>,0.000752695,0.000144944,0.0000162,3.72*10^-6,2.67*10^-6,0.316358,<<904>>},{Automatic}][<<1>>]<=0,<<1>>}. The initial region specified may not contain any feasible points. Changing the initial region or specifying explicit initial points may provide a better solution.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann No, they aren't. They are clearly incomplete.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Thank you for your comment! Were you able to run it without any kernel issues?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I have updated the data sets so that they are better now

Comment: @mathemagician617 Yes  it runs without crash but gives several messages

Comment: Hm. "NelderMead" was probably not a good idea. It seems to work when I remove it. I think the remaining messages pop up only because the iterates of the optimization algorithm temporarily leave the domains of `f1` and `f2`. Since the final point is feasible, I would not wonder to much about that. But I am not sure whether the point found is indeed the global optimum.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thank you very much for your help! Your code seems to work on the subset of my data that I provided, however when I extend it to my full data set the kernel quits. Is there any reason you can think of that this might be happening?

Comment: Hard to tell _without the full data_. Maybe you can load it up somewhere and post a link here?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher https://www.dropbox.com/s/v6pvncyqhkv9sok/Optimization%20Attempt.nb?dl=0 this is a link to a dropbox with a mathematica file that contains all of my data as well as the code you suggested. You should be able to download it using the download button in the upper left please let me know if it doesn't work. Thank you !

Comment: Thank you for the data. The kernel indeed crashes (segfault?). This is something for the developers.

Comment: However, a piecewise-linear function (that's what you generate with `InterpolationOrder -> 1`) attains its maximum and minimum always on a vertex of the underlying triangulation. So `pos = Position[data1[[All, 2]], _?(# <= 0.5 &)];
minind = Ordering[Extract[data2[[All, 2]], pos], -1, 1][[1]];
minimum = data2[[pos[[minind, 1]], 1]]
minvalue = data2[[pos[[minind, 1]], 2]]` should give you the minimal point.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thank you very much! I'm very new to Mathematica. How do I contact the developers about the kernel crash?

Comment: https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=technical

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thank you again!

Comment: You're welcome!